# Sharepoint 2016 How to remove /SitePages/ after url?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-on-prem

I have **Sharepoint 2016 on premise**.

I'm trying to remove the /SitePages/ from url, currently I have this url: http://example.com/IT/SitePages/home.aspx, I want to just have http://example.com/IT/home.aspx.

I found a similar question on stack exchange, practically I just enabled Publishing Feature on site, and move home.aspx there, but it did not work, instead I had http://example.com/IT/Pages/home.aspx

I tried to move home.aspx out of SitePages folder in Sharepoint Designer, and it resolved to the correct url http://example.com/IT/home.aspx, however, it shows an error, and does not show anything.
This is the id of error:  3ca8669f-c42a-f004-ab05-edbfdbc80097

I guess I would need to change something in paths if I wan't to have my home.aspx out of SitePages folder.
Please help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think it is possible. Pages need to be stored in a **library** that will be contained in the URL. I think that is why you cannot move the page to the root of the site using SharePoint Designer.